# scroll div but not entire webview

Tags: scroll, uiwebview, overflow

Is it possible to prevent a uiwebview from scrolling around, but to also have a div that can scroll?

I have a jquery navbar and want a scrollable div underneath with many images. I'd like to be able to scroll through the images while the navbar remains fixed.

Initially the whole webview was moving around so I used this to stop all scrolling.

webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

but now I want the div to still be scrollable.
I have the div style set to

```
overflow:auto
```

but it does not seem to move.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong div set to overflow:auto.
So it worked after setting the correct one to scroll.